# How to fix error: "symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libQt5DBus.so.5: undefined symbol"?

Tags: ubuntu, python, libraries, python3

I was using GNS3 network simulator fine for a while & then after few days
When I start GNS3 Network Simulator, it is giving out following error, not sure what caused this.

**$ sudo gns3**

```
GNS3 GUI version 1.5.2
Copyright (c) 2007-2016 GNS3 Technologies Inc.
your locale en_IN.ISO8859-1 encoding is not UTF-8, switching to the UTF-8 version...
2016-12-23 22:57:53 INFO logger.py:107 Log level: INFO
/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/bin/python: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libQt5DBus.so.5: undefined symbol: _Z28qEnvironmentVariableIntValuePKcPb
```

I tried reinstalling gns3 but the error persisted.

While Un-installing, I got the following warnings:

```
dpkg: warning: while removing gns3-gui, directory '/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/lib/python3.4/__pycache__' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing gns3-gui, directory '/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/bin' not empty so not removed
Removing gns3-server (1.5.2~trusty1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing gns3-server, directory '/usr/share/gns3/gns3-server/lib/python3.4/__pycache__' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing gns3-server, directory '/usr/share/gns3/gns3-server/bin' not empty so not removed
```

So I removed /usr/share/gns3* and then tried installing GNS3 no luck.

Tried the following suggestions made in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204953/189690)
Commented the line `"/usr/local/lib"` in the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf` but no use.

Also when I tried installing GNS3 through Ubuntu Software Center

[image]

Comment: please state your question clearer and add more details.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

After having removed/commented out `/usr/local/lib` in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf`, you also need to run `sudo ldconfig` to update the library cache.